# Does the Java JVM guarantee the correct "wait" will be notified when calling "notify"?

Tags: java, multithreading

According to a colleague, JVM does not guarantee that when calling "notify" on an object, the correct "wait" will be notified at that time. He says there can be a case when a previous notify which is not valid anymore is delivered at an invalid time.

Is this true? If so, how/why is this, and what use is the wait/notify mechanism if you cannot assume something as basic as this will work?

Comment: According to the Java Docs `Object#notify` *"Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the implementation"* - As to choosing an invalid object, I can't commit, but I guess it would come down to the specific implementation of the lock monitor API.

Comment: I think you should let the colleague define "correct" and "valid" a bit more. I do not believe that "something basic as this" does not work. Please provide more details or ideally a code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For java.lang.Object.notify, The Javadoc says:

> Wakes up a single thread that is waiting on this object's monitor. If
>   any threads are waiting on this object, one of them is chosen to be
>   awakened. The choice is arbitrary and occurs at the discretion of the
>   implementation. A thread waits on an object's monitor by calling one
>   of the wait methods.

Here is a pattern to wait for a particular condition:

```
synchronized( lock ) {
   while( conditionEvaluation( data )) {
      lock.wait();
   }
}
```

The counterpart should use `java.lang.Object.notifyAll()` to ensure the vivacity of the application. Even if today, it's only one waiter, after many evolutions of the software, it may be several waiters in the future, so `notifyAll()` is more robust than `notify()`.

Comment: The choice between notify() and notifyAll() depends on whether you need a single thread thread or all threads waiting on a monitor to resume work. This is clearly driven by what that code is supposed to be doing, so both have a reason they exist. In that sense notifyAll() is not more robust than notify(). In fact calling notifyAll() where only one thread would normally be expected to run does not add anything to the liveliness of the application.

Comment: -1 for `conditionEvaluation()` out of synchronized block: it is possible that in the time gap between call to `conditionEvaluation` and the `lock.wait()`, another thread change condition and call `notify`, but the current thread would not notice this and would wait forever.

Comment: Your pattern is not quite correct. The while loop needs to be inside the synchronized block.

Comment: @Aubin wait releases the monitor but once wait completes, the monitor gets reacquired (the thread will block if necessary until the monitor is available). Cf the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29), which among other things gives an example of the correct pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Each object that waits on an intrinsic lock will enter the lock's wait set. When you invoke notify on the lock object, one of the threads in its wait set will be chosen to resume work. The only guarantee that the JVM offers is that the waiting threads will be **eventually** notified. One of the main reasons for this non-deterministic behavior is the way suspended threads are chosen to run by the JVM, which is arbitrary. In addition however, locks in java implement a non-fair locking policy which permits thread barging. This simply means that it is permissible for new lock requests to jump ahead of the lock's wait set, it the lock is available at the time of the request. The justification behind this is that given substantial contention, there might be some (potentially significant) delay before choosing and resuming a suspended thread in the wait set and the time it actually runs. Any incoming lock request from a thread could therefore utilize this time delay to immediately run, in the hope that it will have released the lock by the time the resumed thread is ready to run. For example consider the following sequence of events:

1. Thread A that previously has acquired monitor X calls notify()
2. Thread B waiting on monitor X has chosen to be suspended (arbitrarily).
3. Thread C tries to acquire monitor X, sees that it is available and acquires it.
4. Thread C runs (despite thread B is currently in the process of being resumed)
5. Thread C finishes execution and releases monitor X, just before thread B is actually run.
6. Thread B is ready to run so it acquires the lock and starts execution.

It should be evident that between step 2 and 6 there exists some time interval where no threads are actually using the lock. Thread C barges in and utilizes the time interval as an optimization. The downside of this of course is the risk of not releasing the lock at the time thread B is ready to run, which at that time thread B will notice that the lock is unavailable and will enter the wait set again. Statistically however it can be proven that non-fair locking offers better performance in most situations.

As an aside note, you could use fair locks where waiting threads are resumed in the order they acquired the lock, but in practice this offers worse performance. Read more about this here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not true. When a thread invokes notify, one waiting thread is awakened (if such a thread exists, otherwise notification is lost). Probably your colleague had in mind "spurious notify", which can awake a thread when in fact no other thread invoked `notify` or `notifyAll`. To filter "spurious notify", each `notify` invocation should accompanied with some change in monitored object state, and the waiting threads should check that state:

```
 synchronized void up() {
    counter++;
    notify();
 }
 synchronized void down() {
   while (counter==0) {
      wait();
   }
   counter--;
 }
```

Note checking state in `down()` is done before call to wait(), as it could be changed before the invocation and the notification is lost. In other words, the real information is passed with object's state, and wait/notify only help to avoid polling. Never rely on notifications without changing an object's state.